# Identify which td element was click if none of the td have ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update a **`<div>`** with a table using jQuery. I want to add a **`click`** handler to each **`<td>`**, but the **`click`** handler will be different for each **`<td>`**. How do you tell which **`<td>`** was clicked if it doenst have a **`id`**?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    $.post("controller.php",{ },
    function(data){
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      var object;             

      //add to a table...
      var t = "<table id='newstable' class='table table-dark table-hover'><thead><tr><th>Post Subject</th><th>Last Post</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {  // for each row
        object = obj[i];
        t += "<tr>";                        
        t += "<td colspan='2'>" + object[Object.keys(object)[0]] + "</td>";  // the property value, not the property name 
        //future lastpost td
        t += '</tr>';
      }
      t += '</tbody></table>';
      alert(t);

      $("#main-container").html(t);
    });
  });
});
```

I understand that in order to get the id you must use this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mycontainer").on('click', '#newtable tbody tr td', function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

but what if the **`id`** wasn't set?

Anyone have any recommendations? or guidance? Thanks

I tried to code Daniel Lizik advice and here is what I came up with. It doesnt work. Any ideas how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main-container").on('click','#newstable tbody tr td',function(event){       
        var clickedTd = event.target;       
        var newsTd;

        $("#newstable td").each( function(){
            newsTd = $(this);                   
            if(clickedTd == newsTd){
                alert("they match");
            } else {
                alert("no match");
            }
        });         

    });
});
```

Comment: loop through all `td` in match which one came from `event.target`

Comment: Is it object[Object.keys(object)[0]] or object[Object.keys(object)[i]]? And if the latter, is it unique? Because if it is, perhaps  event.target.innerHTML will work for you. Otherwise it is not clear to me what you mean by saying you know which one was clicked.

Comment: @DanielLizik ill give it a try. thanks for the idea

Comment: @Ried the "object[Object.keys(object)[0]]" is basically text being put there. i was wondering how to access the text in jquery if you give the td a id

Comment: @Daniel Lizik I been working on trying to implement your advice but cant seem to get the code. I will update my post with the code I came up with. Maybe you could write an answer. I feel like your answer is what I am looking for. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to get the coordinates of your cell. I'll give you an example below. You can then determine for each coordinate the actions to take. Otherwise you can also add for each element td a data-attribute in which you pass information that you will use for your javascript processing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mycontainer").on('click', '#newtable tbody tr td', function() {
        var colIndex = $(this).index();
        var rowIndex = $(this).parents('tr').index();
        alert(colIndex + ',' + rowIndex);
    });
});
```

Comment: coordinate wont always be the same. different content will be placed there. thanks for your reply tho

Comment: coordinate will always be the same, it's just a grid.

Comment: sorry for my bad english. I mean a coordinate system wouldnt work because something placed in the first row first column could be changed to the nth row first column, it wont always be in the exact position.